# How to remove the outer indentation of the image?

Tags: css, sass, background, background-image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j1xq.png)

margin:0 and padding:0 doesnt work

SCSS Code I entred SCSS code because CSS code in one line

```
body{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;


}

    header{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
background: url("img/main-img.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 680px;
height: 680px;
```

Html code

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Feautures</li>
            <li>Demos</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you had inserted the `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` into your `<header>` element and not your `<body>`. To get rid of the white space on the outside of your image, you just need `margin: 0;` on your `<body>`.

To show how this works, run the snippet below and select the full page option in the top-right corner.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
 
  /* The solution */
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  /* Changed for example */
  background: url("https://static.structube.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/900x698/9a534115b6b626c8b0e5bcde0743ce76/0/1/01-01.71.76.70_plant_cereus.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  
  height: 680px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Feautures</li>
      <li>Demos</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if I misunderstood your post.